# Node js bodyparser ajax call and output in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, ajax

I am very new to node.js and want to do a simple json parse using ajax call, and output the json content in an html page.

I am using express csv2json converter to convert a csv file to json, and using bodyparser to try to parse the json.

This is my app.js file:

```
//init app with express, util, body-parser, csv2json
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var sys = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;

//register body-parser to handle json from res / req
app.use( bodyParser.json() );

//register public dir to serve static files (html, css, js)
app.use( express.static( path.join(__dirname, "public") ) );

/** csv2json **/

var csvConverter=new Converter({constructResult:false, toArrayString:true});
var readStream=require("fs").createReadStream("world_data.csv"); 

var writeStream=require("fs").createWriteStream("outpuData.json");

readStream.pipe(csvConverter).pipe(writeStream);

console.log(writeStream);

/** handle HTTP METHODS **/

app.get('outputData.sjon', function (req, res) {
  var answer = JSON.parse(req.params);
  res.send( writeStream );
  });

// bind server to port
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Here is my ajax.js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/app.js",
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
    // Handle returned data
    }, error: function(jqXHR, text, err) {
    // Handle error if occured
    }
});
```

Here I want to output the json content in an html table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="table_head">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>birth rate / 1000</th>
            <th>cellphones / 100</th>
            <th>children / woman</th>
            <th>electric usage</th>
            <th>internet usage</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_body">
        <!-- list countrys with ajax -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The json output file gets saved like in  this data example:

```
{"id":"001","name":"Brazil","birth rate per 1000":"16.405","cell phones per 100":"90.01936334","children per woman":"1.862","electricity consumption per capita":"2201.808724","gdp_per_capita":"4424.758692","gdp_per_capita_growth":"-1.520402823","inflation annual":"8.228535058","internet user per 100":"39.22","life expectancy":"74","military expenditure percent of gdp":"1.615173655","gps_lat":"-14.235004000","gps_long":"-51.925280000"}
```

Any info on how to bind the app.js file to ajax.js together and output the json it in index.html would be very helpful. Thanks